# Mongorestore really slow (on replica set)

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I began using MongoDB, I've create a ReplicaSet, set 3 Nodes (Primary, Secondary, Arbiter).

I was really satisfied about failover, load tests, performance.

Last test was to restore from mongodump a BSON File.
I've installed Mongo on windows 2012 R2 platform, I used the shells mongodump e mongorestore, 
Dump has required just few secs the generated BSON file was really small 4mb.

When I tried to restore the BSON, the mongorestore stopped working almost immediately at (21%), I waited few minutes without any progress.

log:

> connected to: ap2-mongodb00:27017
>   2014-12-09T15:15:16.558+0100 E:\ap2-mongodb01\dump_2014-09-12\test\Contacts.bson
>   2014-12-09T15:15:16.558+0100    going into namespace [test.Contacts]
>   Restoring to test.Contacts without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
>   2014-12-09T15:15:26.582+0100            Progress: 1053740/4807174       21%     (bytes)

After 15 minutes, it was still blocked

The Primary Mongo CPU was fixed al 12%, no way to complete the restore.

Have you any suggestion?

Comment: What does it say in the mongod logs?

Comment: Hi, I see periodically this error when on service call from ARBITER SERVER: 

2014-12-20T14:00:33.373+0100 [conn21] command admin.$cmd command: replSetHeartbeat { replSetHeartbeat: "rsColibri", v: 5, pv: 1, checkEmpty: false, from: "ap2-mongodba00:30000", fromId: 2 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:160 0ms

ERROR:

127.0.0.1:64376 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:64376]